# SWIFT: SKSpriteNode setting alpha to 0 vs. removing it from it's parent

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a problem and I have to admit, I'm a bit of confused. I have to show/hide some SpriteNodes (those are some option buttons that will appear if the game is over). If the retry "button" (SpriteNode) is pressed by the player, the method that is called by that touch is setting it's alpha to zero. But sometimes it remains "active"(means alpha remains 1), behind other sprites and while the game is played again and the nodes that are in front of it are moving and it becomes visible. That is very confusing and being a random behavior I was thinking if removing it from it's parent (which is self, anyway) and adding it again when it's necessary is a better way to approach that kind of situations.
The code is like:

```
func restartGame()
{
restartButon.alpha = 0
......................
}
if nodeAtPoint(location).name == "someName"
{
restartGame()
}
```

It's good to mention that the appearance of this button is made by SKAction.fadeAlphaTo(1,1.5) and it's initially alpha is set to 0 in didMoveToView() override method.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you still seeing it, it obviously means something in your program is setting the alpha to 1.

Why not just set the node's `hidden` property to true? This will hide it.

In general, if this is for UI elements which are not always displayed, you are better off by controlling these pieces by a parent node which can contain all of the UI elements. For example, you could have a "menu" node, which contains all of the button nodes. Note this is very simplistic in that more complicated UIs would require a more complicated node hierarchy. But this would work if your UI is layer "floating" over the game.

The advantage of this is you could either remove everything by removing the parent from the tree or just set the parent's `hidden` property to true

Comment: Yes. I know there are lot of solutions. hidden = true is one of them. Another is to remove the nodes (I really don't know which is optimal from the memory management point of view). Sometimes it remains with alpha 1, sometimes no. As I said before this behavior is (or at least it seams) randomly. I really don't know whose bug is this. Mine or compiler's. It is weird anyway. I did removed the sprites but... This situation decreased my trust.

Comment: If your sprite is a subclass of `SKNode`/`SKSpriteNode`, you could always create the setter `- (void)setHidden:(BOOL)hidden` and then see who calls it. Or if you haven't you could just create a subclass for the sprite that is exhibiting the issue. More often than not, it is user error. This certainly doesn't mean there isn't an issue with the compiler (this is probably not the issue) or the SDK (more likely than the compiler, still less likely than you).